# Lubuntu live program files

Tags: usb, lubuntu

I recently installed the newest version of lubuntu live to a USB, but as my USB is only 4 gig it wont save the persistence correctly, I was wondering if there was a loophole, that would let me put in a file to be installed onto the temporary hard drive created in the RAM. so my question is, where is the information to load/ install the applications on the USB.

Comment: Please tell us: 1. which version (name of the iso file) that you downloaded; 2. which tool you used to create a persistent live drive; 3. Have you got more than one USB pendrive, hard disk drive or solid state drive? Or are you considering persistence in an internal drive?

Comment: 1. I used lubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso    2. i used PDL-Casper-RW-Creator.exe after using rufus to burn it.   3. i have two 4gb usbs and 1 1gb usb and i cannot use the hard drive on the computer (work)

Comment: The information to load/ install the applications on the USB is stored on a file or partition named casper-rw, Casper-rw can be located anywhere on the boot path from a partition on the internal drive to a partition on the Persistent USB to a file on the root of the USB to a folder anywhere on the drive if the folder name is listed as persistent-path in grub.

Answer (score 0):

### What you can do with your two 4GB USB pendrives

I think the best thing you can do with your current USB drives is the following.

- Boot from the drive with Lubuntu 17.10.1 (which is live-only)
- Install [**`mkusb`**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb),

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository universe  # only for standard Ubuntu

  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mkusb/ppa  # and press Enter
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install mkusb mkusb-nox usb-pack-efi
  ```

  This works but will not be persistent.
- Make the `lubuntu-17.10.1-desktop-amd64.iso` file available to the live-only system (by connecting a drive with the file and copying or downloading the file again).
- Use **mkusb** to create a persistent live Lubuntu system in the second 4 GB USB pendrive. See this link: [help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/persistent)

  Select 100% for persistence (which may cause complaints, but it should work anyway).
- Shutdown and remove the first (live-only) USB drive.
- Boot into the second and now persistent live USB pendrive. You can stop here.
- If you want more drive space for persistence, you can connect the first (live-only) USB drive.
- Use **gparted** to

  - remove the partitions on the first (live-only) USB drive,
  - create a partition with an `ext4` file system
  - and put the label **`home-rw`** on that partition.
  - If problems with gparted, install mkusb in this persistent live system and use it to wipe the first mibibyte. After that gparted should work (Select 'device' and create a partition table and after that a partition ...)
- Reboot into the persistent live USB drive and select **Try Lubuntu** (*not* with  persistence).

  - Connect the `home-rw` USB drive.
  - copy the content of `/home` to the home partition, dry run to check,

    ```
     sudo rsync -Havn /media/lubuntu/casper-rw/upper/home/ /media/lubuntu/home-rw
    ```

    and the real copying (without the option **`n`**)

    ```
     sudo rsync -Hav /media/lubuntu/casper-rw/upper/home/ /media/lubuntu/home-rw
    ```
- Reboot with both USB pendrives connected.

  - If you cannot select the correct USB drive for booting, the one with the operating system, you can boot and when at the grub menu connect the other USB drive (with `home-rw`). Then continue from the grub menu.
  - Now you should have a persistent live system with a maximum 3 GB `casper-rw` partition for the root file system (to install programs etc) and a 4 GB `home-rw` partition for `/home`, and you can use a total of 7 GB for persistence.
  - When you have confirmed, that your system is persistent, and that it uses both `casper-rw` and `home-rw`, you can remove `/media/lubuntu/casper-rw/upper/home/`.

### Check that it looks like this:

You can right-click on the screenshot and open it in a big window to see it in full size.

[image]

Command lines and output from them:

```
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           384M  6.1M  377M   2% /run
/dev/sdc4       925M  925M     0 100% /cdrom
/dev/loop0      863M  863M     0 100% /rofs
/cow            2.6G  137M  2.3G   6% /
/dev/sdb1       3.7G  8.0M  3.4G   1% /home
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.9G  4.0K  1.9G   1% /tmp
tmpfs           384M  8.0K  384M   1% /run/user/999
/dev/sdc5       2.6G  137M  2.3G   6% /media/lubuntu/casper-rw
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdb p
Model: SanDisk Cruzer Blade (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 4005MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  4005MB  4003MB  primary  ext4

lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo parted /dev/sdc p
Model: JetFlash Transcend 4GB (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 4052MB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name     Flags
 2      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB               primary  bios_grub
 3      2097kB  258MB   256MB   fat32        primary  boot, esp
 4      258MB   1247MB  989MB                primary
 5      1247MB  4051MB  2804MB  ext2         primary
 1      4051MB  4052MB  681kB                primary  msftdata

lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME   FSTYPE   LABEL               UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
loop0  squashfs                                                          /rofs
sda                                                                      
├─sda1 vfat                         AD68-7CA2                            
├─sda2 ext4     lubuntu             0162276e-c99e-43b5-87c3-59bb064af44b 
├─sda3 swap                         b66eb718-af47-41d0-9932-e35cdaae11c3 [SWAP]
└─sda4 ext4     xubuntu-core        ad262cdc-ba80-4536-b686-1caf1b5ef441 
sdb                                                                      
└─sdb1 ext4     home-rw             d43d50f7-f372-47da-9f22-eb075e725164 /home
sdc                                                                      
├─sdc1                                                                   
├─sdc2                                                                   
├─sdc3 vfat     usbboot             BF5D-50BE                            
├─sdc4 iso9660  Lubuntu 17.10 amd64 2018-01-06-00-29-08-00               /cdrom
└─sdc5 ext4     casper-rw           03f25a82-d74b-497e-b86e-a6efaf749d6f /media/lubuntu/casper-rw
sr0                                                                      
zram0                                                                    [SWAP]
zram1                                                                    [SWAP]
zram2                                                                    [SWAP]
zram3                                                                    [SWAP]
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$ sudo lsblk -m
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
loop0    863M root  disk  brw-rw----
sda    111.8G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1   512M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2    15G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda3   3.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda4    15G root  disk  brw-rw----
sdb      3.7G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdb1   3.7G root  disk  brw-rw----
sdc      3.8G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdc1   665K root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdc2     1M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdc3   244M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sdc4   943M root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sdc5   2.6G root  disk  brw-rw----
sr0     1024M root  cdrom brw-rw----
zram0  478.9M root  disk  brw-rw----
zram1  478.9M root  disk  brw-rw----
zram2  478.9M root  disk  brw-rw----
zram3  478.9M root  disk  brw-rw----
lubuntu@lubuntu:~$
```

### More powerful alternative

Things will work better (and be easier), if you get a [fast USB 3 pendrive with at least 16 GB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Prerequisites), and create a persistent live Lubuntu system in that drive.